# How to set up Catch2 in Bazel project

Tags: c++, testing, bazel, catch-unit-test, catch2

I have started a simple C++ project that uses Bazel as build system and would like to add Catch2 to it, as test framework.

This is what my project looks like so far:

```
WORKSPACE -> empty file
src/
  Money.hpp
  Money.cpp
BUILD
```

where BUILD is just

```py
cc_library(
  name = "Money",
  srcs = ["Money.cpp"],
  hdrs = ["Money.hpp"]
)
```

I would like to be able to create tests for each `cc_library`, in this case for `Money`. I tried setting it up but got confused with Catch2 main. Any advice on how to do this best is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some back and forth I managed to get this working, for Bazel 0.16.1 and Catch2 2.4.0.

First let's create directory `test/` next to `src/`, to keep our tests there.

In order to use Catch2, we need to download `catch.hpp`. Catch2 is header only library, meaning that one file is all we need. I put it in `test/vendor/catch2/`.
Then, we need to define to bazel how to use it. In `test/vendor/catch2` we create following BUILD file:

```py
cc_library(
  name = "catch2",
  hdrs = ["catch.hpp"],
  visibility = ["//test:__pkg__"]
)
```

Now Bazel recognizes Catch2 as a library. We added visibility attribute, so that it can be used from the `//test` package (which is defined by BUILD in `/test` directory).

Next, Catch2 requires us to define one translation unit with correctly defined main method. Following their instructions, we create `test/main.cpp` file:

```cpp
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch.hpp"
```

Now, we write our test, in `test/Money.test.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "catch.hpp"
#include "Money.hpp"

TEST_CASE("Money works.") {
  ...
}
```

Finally, we need to explain to Bazel how to build all this. Notice that we directly included Money.hpp and catch.hpp in our files, with no relative path, so that is also smth we need to keep in mind.
We create following `test/BUILD` file:

```py
# We describe to Bazel how to build main.cpp.
# It includes "catch.hpp" directly, so we need to add
# "-Itest/vendor/catch2" compiler option.
cc_library(
    name = "catch-main",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"],
    copts = ["-Itest/vendor/catch2"],
    deps = [
        "//test/vendor/catch2"
    ]
)

# Here we define our test. It needs to build together with the catch2
# main that we defined above, so we add it to deps. We directly
# include src/Money.hpp and test/vendor/catch2/catch.hpp in
# Money.test.cpp, so we need to add their parent directories as copts.
# We also add Money and catch2 as dependencies.
cc_test(
    name = "Money",
    srcs = ["Money.test.cpp"],
    copts = ["-Itest/vendor/catch2/", "-Isrc/"],
    deps = [
        # Or "//test/vendor/catch2:catch2", it is the same.
        "//test/vendor/catch2",
        "catch-main",
        "//src:Money"
    ]
)

# Test suite that runs all the tests.
test_suite(
    name = "all-tests",
    tests = [
        "Money"
    ]
)
```

Finally, we just need to add `visibility` attribute to `src/BUILD` so that it can be accessed from tests. We modify `src/BUILD` to look like this:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "Money",
    srcs = ["Money.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["Money.hpp"],
    visibility = ["//test:__pkg__"]
)
```

Final file structure looks like this:

```
WORKSPACE
src/
  Money.hpp
  Money.cpp
  BUILD
test/
  BUILD
  main.cpp
  Money.test.cpp
  vendor/
    catch2/
      catch.hpp
      BUILD
```

Now you can run your tests with `bazel test //test:all-tests`!

I created Github repo with this example, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/Martinsos/tdd-by-example/tree/03d5bdb62905e0f7820343d2007f67010a0b189b).
I also turned it into a [blog post](http://martinsosic.com/cpp/bazel/catch2/2018/08/28/cpp-bazel-catch2.html).

Answer (score 5):

Catch2 (v2.13.0) is supported by Bazel out of the box.

**Example**

*WORKSPACE.bazel*:

```
workspace(name = "Catch2Demo")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "catch2",
    strip_prefix = "Catch2-2.13.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/archive/v2.13.0.tar.gz"],
)
```

*BUILD.bazel*:

```
cc_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = ["my_test.cpp"],
    defines = ["CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN"],
    deps = [
        "@catch2",
    ],
)
```

*my_test.cpp*:

```
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>

unsigned int Factorial( unsigned int number ) {
    return number <= 1 ? number : Factorial(number-1)*number;
}

TEST_CASE( "Factorials are computed", "[factorial]" ) {
    REQUIRE( Factorial(1) == 1 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(2) == 2 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(3) == 6 );
    REQUIRE( Factorial(10) == 3628800 );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Catch2 v3 (3.1.1)

Catch2 v3 is split into multiple headers, requires C++14 or greater, and is no longer header-only, which slightly changes things

###### WORKSPACE.bazel:

```
workspace(name = "Catch2Demo")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "catch2",
    strip_prefix = "Catch2-3.1.1",
    urls = ["https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/archive/v3.1.1.tar.gz"],
)
```

###### BUILD.bazel:

```
cc_test(
    name = "my_test",
    srcs = ["my_test.cpp"],
    copts = ["-std=c++14"],
    deps = [
        "@catch2//:catch2_main",
    ],
)
```

###### my_test.cpp:

```
#include <catch2/catch_test_macros.hpp>

unsigned int Factorial( unsigned int number ) {
    return number <= 1 ? number : Factorial(number-1)*number;
}

TEST_CASE( "Factorials are computed", "[factorial]" ) {
REQUIRE( Factorial(1) == 1 );
REQUIRE( Factorial(2) == 2 );
REQUIRE( Factorial(3) == 6 );
REQUIRE( Factorial(10) == 3628800 );
}
```

Now, run tests with

```
bazelisk test //:my_test --cxxopt='-std=c++14'
```

Answer (score -1):

Bazel support was upstreamed to catch2: https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/pull/1923

Using that, you just need to add to your WORKSPACE:

```
http_archive(
  name = "com_github_catchorg_catch2",
  urls = ["https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/archive/v2.12.1.tar.gz"],
  strip_prefix = "Catch2-2.12.1",
  sha256 = "e5635c082282ea518a8dd7ee89796c8026af8ea9068cd7402fb1615deacd91c3",
)
```

(replace the version and sha256 with the right values if you want a newer version).

Then your build file can simply do:

```
cc_library(
  name = "test_main",
  srcs = ["test_main.cpp"],
  deps = ["@com_github_catchorg_catch2//:catch2"],
)
```

with a `test_main.cpp` that contains:

```c
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN
#include "catch2/catch.hpp"
```

Finally, you can define tests like this:

```
cc_library(
  name = "my_test",
  srcs = ["my_test.cpp"],
  deps = [
      ":test_main",
      "@com_github_catchorg_catch2//:catch2",
  ],
)
```

Comment: Why do you define a test as a `cc_library` and not `cc_test`?